# Including hyperlinks in Microsoft Word 2013 references

Tags: microsoft-word, hyperlink, citations, bibliography

I'm using the citations feature in Microsoft Word and creating a list of references at the end of my document. An example of the generated reference is:

1. USDOT. ITS Benefits Database. ITS Knowldege Resources. [Online] [Cited: 7 6, 2016.] www.itsbenefits.its.dot.gov.

Is there a way to get the url (www.itsbenefits.its.dot.gov) to be an automatically generated hyperlink, as it is when I type URLs into the main text of the document? If so, how do I do this? Right now, it doesn't even let me edit the entry to make the URL a link, and if it did, I'd lose it anytime I auto-updated the references.

I'm using Word 2013.

Answer (score 0):

The following macro code seems to work for me:

```
Sub Add_Hyperlinks_Bibliography()
On Error Resume Next
Set rngSearch = Selection
For I = 1 To ActiveDocument.Bibliography.Sources.Count
 Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
 strStyle = "Intensieve benadrukking"
 strSearch = ActiveDocument.Bibliography.Sources.Item(I).Field("URL")
 strAddress = strSearch
 With rngSearch.Find
    Do While .Execute(findText:=strSearch, MatchCase:=False, MatchWholeWord:=False) = True
        With rngSearch 'we will work with what is found as it will be the selection
            ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=rngSearch, Address:=strAddress
            .Style = ActiveDocument.Styles(strStyle) 'throw the style on it after the link
        End With
        rngSearch.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        'keep it moving
    Loop
 End With
Next I
On Error GoTo 0
Set rngSearch = Nothing
End Sub
```

Obviously, you would have to execute this code each time you refresh the bibliography-field